# How to fix code to enter a covariance matrix using lavaan package

Tags: r

I am receiving the following error message when entering a covariance matrix using lavaan:

> Error in lav_matrix_lower2full(c(0.77, 0.38, 0.65, 0.39, 0.39, 0.62, -0.25,  : 
>     p == round(p, 0) is not TRUE

I've used the following code before with no issue.

```
Full.cor<-lav_matrix_lower2full(c(.77,.38,.65,.39,.39,.62,-.25,-.32,-.27,6.09,.31,.29,.26,-.36,7.67,.24,.25,.19,-.18,.51,1.69,-3.16,-3.56,-2,63,6.09,-3.12,-4.58,204.79,-.92,-.88,-.72,.88,-1.49,-1.41,16.53,7.24))
```

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?lav_matrix_lower2full` (bold-face mine):

> The ‘lav_matrix_vechr_reverse’ (alias: ‘lav_matrix_vechu_reverse’
>       and ‘lav_matrix_lower2full’) creates a symmetric matrix, **given
>       only the lower triangular elements**, row by row. If diagonal =
>       FALSE, an diagonal with zero elements is added.

For any symmetric `n × n` matrix there are `n(n+1)/2` lower triangular elements (including the diagonal).

The error arises from you not providing the correct amount of "unpacked" matrix elements.

For example for a `3 × 3` matrix we need to provide 6 elements

```
lav_matrix_lower2full(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    1    3
#[2,]    1    2    4
#[3,]    3    4    5
```

If we do instead

```
lav_matrix_lower2full(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

we get the error

> Error in lav_matrix_lower2full(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)) :
>     p == round(p, 0) is not TRUE

In your case you have 37 elements, which suggests that either

- you have an additional erroneous element for a potential `8 × 8` covariance matrix requiring 36 elements,  or
- you are missing 8 additional elements for a potential `9 × 9` covariance matrix requiring 45 elements.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome @AnthonyHitch; please consider closing the question by setting the green checkmark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy and make it easier for others to identify relevant questions. Thanks.